# popState is delaying by one backward click

Tags: javascript, pushstate

Either I miss understand popstate or I am going crazy can't figure out what is going on here. I'm using firefox and everytime I navigate a little and try and click the back button I get zero state but when I click it again I then get state? Seems something is delayed. Must be doing this all wrong. Need some help.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function makeid() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));
    }
    return text;
}


/* Global Variables */

var routes = [];

/* Recursivly Load Ajax */

function load_state(process_states){
    var state = process_states.shift();
    if (typeof(state) !== 'undefined'){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: state.source,
            success: function(html) {
                $(state.target).empty().append(html);

                // Next itteration
                load_state(process_states);
            },
            async:false,
            cache:false,
        });

    }
}

/* Load page from URL */

function load_url(route, states, name){

    // Register route
    routes.push({'route': route, 'states': states, 'name': name});

    // Read current url
    var url = window.location.pathname;

    // Test url matches route
    if (route.test(url)){

        // Process matched route
        var process_states = states.slice();
        load_state(process_states);

        // Record state change
        history.pushState({'states': states}, makeid(), url);
    }
}

/* Pop State Event  */

$(window).on('popstate', function(evt){
    if (evt.state) {

        // Process route
        var states = evt.originalEvent.state.states;
        var process_states = states.slice();
        load_state(process_states);
    }
});

/* Click Link Envent */

$(document).on('click', '[data-name]', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();

    // Locate state with name
    var name = $(this).attr('data-name');
    var states_found = $.grep(routes, function(evt){ return evt.name === name; });

    // If state found load state
    if (states_found.length !== 0){
        var states = states_found[0].states;
        var process_states = states.slice();
        load_state(process_states);

        // Record state change
        history.pushState({'states': states.states}, 'ajax',name);
    }
});

/* Routing Table */

load_url(/^\/$/i, [
    {'target': '.body-ajax', 'source': '/ajax/public/'},
    {'target': '.page-ajax', 'source': '/ajax/public/home/'},
], '/');

load_url(/^\/two\/$/i, [
    {'target': '.body-ajax', 'source': '/ajax/public/'},
    {'target': '.page-ajax', 'source': '/ajax/public/two/'},
], '/two/');

load_url(/^\/contact\/$/i, [
    {'target': '.body-ajax', 'source': '/ajax/public/'},
    {'target': '.page-ajax', 'source': '/ajax/public/contact/'},
], '/contact/');

});
```

Comment: you have a typo `cashe:false` should be `cache: false`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Any other problems you might see?